# Batch script programmimng: save line value from a txt file into a variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to read a text file where every line has a number. Negative numbers need to be replaced by 0 and written to a new file along with the rest of the positive numbers.

The problem is that I want to save the value of a line, i.e. %%a into a new variable. Then I'll check if the first character of that variable is '-' if so, I'll set the value to 0 for that line in the final file if not, it will remain as is.

But I cannot save the line value into anything. Below is my code. 
3.txt is the original file, tempfile.txt is the final file.

```
set filem=3.txt
set tempfile=tempfile.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%filem%) do (
    set linevalue=%%a
    IF %linevalue:~0,1% EQU - (
    echo 0>>%tempfile%
    ) ELSE (
    echo %%a>>%tempfile%
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: Thank you for including a description of your problem and your attempts to solve it. Please also include a description of the problem - that is why the code that you show does not work. As part of a Minimal Example we expect that you tell us what you expected to happen, and what actually happened.

Comment: I have closed your question as a duplicate, (as the issue is that you're are trying to both define a variable and use its expanded value within the same parsed code block). _I have additionally included an answer to assist your understanding of the information in the linked question and answers._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your numbers are really integers, you could give the following method a try:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "filem=3.txt"
Set "tempfile=tempfile.txt"
If Exist "%filem%" (
    (   For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=]" %%G In (
            '""%__AppDir__%find.exe" /N /V ""<"%filem%""'
        ) Do If "%%H" == "" (
            Echo=%%H
        ) Else (
            If %%H Lss 0 (
                Echo 0
            ) Else Echo %%H
        )
    )>"%tempfile%"
)
Pause
```

If they're floating point numbers, you'd be both setting and using variables within the same code block, so you would need to use delayed expansion, *(which was missing from your code)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "filem=3.txt"
Set "tempfile=tempfile.txt"
If Exist "%filem%" (
    (   For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=]" %%G In (
            '""%__AppDir__%find.exe" /N /V ""<"%filem%""'
        ) Do If "%%H" == "" (
            Echo=%%H
        ) Else (
            Set "LineVal=%%H"
            SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            If "!LineVal:~,1!" == "-" (
                Echo 0
            ) Else Echo %%H
            EndLocal
        )
    )>"%tempfile%"
)
Pause
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, when number is negative, it assigns 0, unfortunately when number is positive, it adds a blank space in front of the number, therefore I cannot use. In short, if you have: -1|-6|8|7, I get 0|0| 8| 7. As long as I don't know how to enter an "intro", I typed | instead...

Comment: You must not have copied it correctly, my code adds nothing to any line, it only replaces lines with a minimum of two characters, _(the first being a `-`, with a single one)_. The most likely reason is that you've added a space character yourself, after the `H` on line `12` with the first example, line `15` with the second example. In fact, there should be no trailing spaces on any line of my script, _(any decent text/programming editor should have a trim whitespace ootion)_.

Comment: True, you're right, so I have 2 more problems, first, my file has a space at the begining of every line, I don't know how to get rid of it. On the other hand, my numbers are in exponential notation, for example 2.3e-2, I need the numbers in number notation, in the example 0.023, is it possible to do it? I'm sorry but I'm a physicist, not a programmer, that's why I do not know about coding. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again. I understand. Thanks for your time anyway. I just give up.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you will run the **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** in the same **directory/folder** as your code files, otherwise, edit the **`cd /d "%~dp0"`** adding the full/complete folder of your files.

---

```bat
@echo off 

cd /d "%~dp0"
set "filem=.\3.txt"
type nul >".\tempfile.txt"
set "tempfile=.\tempfile.txt"

for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('type "%filem%"')do (
 echo["%%~a"|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe \-[0-9] >nul && (
   echo[0>>"%tempfile%" ) || ( echo/%%~a%%b>>"%tempfile%" )
)

goto :EOF
```

---